# Can't shift focus to another text input in Firefox in RHEL5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, focus

I am trying out this simple code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".foo").bind("contextmenu",function(){
     $(".boo").focus();      
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type = 'text' class = 'foo' /><input type = 'text' class = 'boo' />
</body>
</html>
```

What it is supposed to do is to shift the focus to the 2nd text input when a right click is done on the first one. This works fine in browsers on Windows, but in `RHEL5`, while checking in Firefox, this doesn't happen, and the focus still remains on the first one.

I tried to change the logic to something like this:

```
$(".foo").click(function(e) {
   if (e.which == 3)
     $(".boo").focus();
});
```

It still doesn't work. However, if I change the last code to `if (e.which == 1)...`, the focus gets shifted on clicking, it doesn't for right click somehow. This problem is happening in `RHEL5` for Firefox, and Firefox, Chrome in Mac. It however, works fine in Safari and Opera on Mac.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change your input classes to IDs, more appropriate here

```
<input type="text" id="foo" /><input type="text" id="boo" />
```

Then try this, simple Javacript, no jQuery required.

```
document.getElementById("foo").onfocus = function(){
  document.getElementById("boo").focus();
}
```

edit: the working solution involved using a timeout in the OP's original code:

```
setTimeout(function(){$(".boo").focus()}, 0)
```

It would work as well with the code above using a timeout.

Comment: that's weird, it works for me on Firefox in Ubuntu. Even old browsers should support that.

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty weird. I am trying to get around by detecting a right mouse down followed by a right mouse up. Then it is working fine..:)

Comment: Update, it doesn't work for Chrome in Mac also. And sorry about Opera for Mac, it works fine.

Comment: can you add console logs to find out what doesn't work: is it the onfocus event not being triggered, or is it the focus call not doing anything.

Comment: Can't seem to find how to log, and what to log. There is no problem with the `contextmenu` event it seems, since of the handler has something like `alert("Foo");`, it does alert. Only when the handler involves shifting the focus does it not work. And that too, only for Firefox and Chrome in Mac and Linux...

Comment: An idea... Try setting a timeout: `setTimeout(function(){$(".boo").focus()}, 0)` instead of your current code

Comment: LOL...it is working with `setTimeout`! Should have though about that, coz I am using the same in a similar context. Weird, isn't it, that the same code is implemented differently in the same browser in different OS? You better incorporate this into this  answer, so that it can be readily accessible to others..

Comment: done. I'm not a big fan of using timeouts like this, but it does help occasionally. I'd suggest avoiding this kind of tricks when possible though :) imagine you are writing a unit test, you won't be able to assert the newly focused field unless you add a timeout in the test...